# Subquerying in SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I am writing a C# application that interfaces with SQL Server CE, but I have encountered one of the many limitations that CE has.

My database has the tables `Customer`, `List`, and `CustomerList`. Customers can be subscribed to many lists and lists can have many customers - so I have the customerlist table as a junction table (columns are `CustomerListId`, `CustomerId`, `ListId` - that's all).

The design is that we have a master list that will always have every customer listed in it.

So in my code I am writing a function that sets all the listed customers to be subscribed to the master list. This is my very simple SQL query:

```
insert into customerlist (CustomerId, ListId)
values (
(select customerid from customer),
(select 1 from list where ShortDesc='Master'))
```

This query does not work in SQL Server CE and I am racking my brains trying to find an alternative that does not involve a painful for-each row-by-row code. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use:

```
INSERT INTO  customerlist (CustomerId, ListId) 
SELECT customerid,1  FROM customer
```

Am I missing something?

Good luck.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear enough. All customers need to be inserted into a specific list named 'Master'. This list is identified by name, not ID (I know this isnt perfect, but I have written code to make sure there will not be duplicates). Therefore I need a query that inserts into the specific 'Master' list.

Comment: Still confused -- you have a list named Master (with ID 1 I presume).  Then the above will insert a single record for each customer into the customerlist table with that Id?

Comment: No the ID of the master list is unknown. However there will only ever be one master list, my C# code makes sure of that.

Comment: Perhaps showing some sample data with desired results.  Not understanding your requirements.  Be happy to help if I did though.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution.

I have first done a C# cmd that gets the ID of the master list.

```
string sqlGetId = "select listid from list where ShortDesc='Master'";
SqlCeCommand cmdGetMasterId = new SqlCeCommand(sqlGetId, DbConnection.ceConnection);
int key = (int)cmdGetMasterId.ExecuteScalar();
```

Then I used that key in a simpler second query:

```
sql2 = "insert into customerlist (CustomerId, ListId) select customerid, " + key + " from customer";
cmd2 = new SqlCeCommand(sql2, DbConnection.ceConnection);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I realize that adding SQL commands with parameters is always better than concatenating - but due to the scope of this application, SQL injection is not a concern.

(Sorry for the simple question/answer, but I am new to this ^^)